# angular-oauth2-oidc does not send access_token to resource server

Tags: angular, spring-boot, keycloak, angular-oauth2-oidc

I am using angular-oauth2-oidc to obtain PKCE flow, but when I call api from resource server, it seem to be not send access_token in the header. I try to check angular-oauth2-oidc get access_token or not but I don't see anything

I think the library will send access_token to http://localhost:8080 right ?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    OAuthModule.forRoot({
      resourceServer: {
          allowedUrls: ['http://localhost:8080'],
          sendAccessToken: true
      }
  })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am using initCodeFlow();

```
export class LoginComponent {
  title = 'for-south-ui';

  constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService, private loginService: LoginService, private oAuthStorage: OAuthStorage) {
    this.configure();
  }

authConfig: AuthConfig = {
    issuer: 'http://localhost:9090/realms/for-south-app',
    redirectUri: window.location.origin,
    clientId: 'for-south-ui',
    scope: 'openid profile email',
    responseType: 'code',
    showDebugInformation: true,
    requestAccessToken: true,
    dummyClientSecret: 'test'
  }
  
  public login() {
    this.loginService.login();
  }
  
  public logoff() {
    this.loginService.logout();
  }

  public getAccessToken() {
    console.log(this.oAuthStorage.getItem('localStorage'));
  }
  
  private configure() {
    this.oauthService.configure(this.authConfig);
    this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new NullValidationHandler();
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();
    this.oauthService.setStorage(this.oAuthStorage);
  }
```

this is request that I sent to resource server

```
export class TopicService {

  private url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/topic/test";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public getTest(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url);
  }
```

[But I don't see any thing in the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEuqH.png)

Comment: That's weird, I don't see any obvious potential cause in your code. The screenshot shows the logs on the server though, have you tried debugging with the developer tools in your browser? They are a bit more reliable for this (the server may filter Authorization headers perhaps? for security?). You could also check out [my sample](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards) and compare against it. The sample does send an access token to its APIs, you can reconfigure it to target your Spring Boot API to test that too.

Comment: did you get any solution for this i am also facing the same issue , when using standalone component